# How to fix ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the `sorted()` in `python` and trying to find the `interpretation` but I get this error.

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Here's my code:

```
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti

X = processed_data[0]
y = prediction

rf = pickle.load(open("original/PermutationModelNew.sav", "rb"))
prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(rf, X)

print("Bias (trainset mean)", bias[0])
c, feature = sorted(zip(contributions[0],X.columns))
```

`X` is the test data and it looks like this:

```
Age DailyRate DistanceFromHome  ... BusinessTravel_ OverTime_ Over18_
0  39       903                2  ...               2         1       1

[1 rows x 28 columns]
```

and `y` looks like this:

```
[0]
```

Can someone please help me to fix this? I am using this [Example](http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/)

Comment: `sorted()` returns generator, I guess there're more than 2 elements, so you got this error.

Comment: Can you help me fix this? What do you mean by `2` elements? @OlvinRoght

Comment: `c, feature = sorted(...)` In this code you're trying to unpack result of `sorted()` in 2 variables. It will work only if there's iterable with 2 items, if there's more or less you'll get an exception.

Comment: you probably want someting like
    'for c, feature in sorted(...)'

Comment: The example you link to has `for c, feature in sorted(...)`. As others have said, you need it here because `sorted()` is returning a generator.

Comment: Try `c, feature = list(*zip(sorted(zip(contributions[0],X.columns))))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght can you elaborate please why `sorted` returns a generator?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, my bad, it returns `list`. Anyway it changes nothing in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how I was doing the sorting for the contribution (I was creating a dictionary with the results and then convert it into a DataFrame, but you don't have to use the dictionary):

```
prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(model, chunk_data)
contr_dict = {}
for i in range(len(chunk_data)):
     contr_dict.setdefault('instance', []).append(i)
     contr_dict.setdefault('prediction', []).append(prediction[i][1])
     contr_dict.setdefault('bias', []).append(bias[i][1])
        
     contribution = contributions[i]
     # sort contributions in descending order
     ids = contribution[:, 1].argsort()[::-1]
     for j in ids:
        contr_dict.setdefault(chunk_data.columns[j][]).append(contribution[j][1])

pd.DataFrame(contr_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
c, feature = list(*zip(sorted(zip(contributions[0],X.columns))))
```

This should solve your error message.